# Fastest way to implement delete, then insert from one db to another?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this SQL now:

```
delete from [db_dest].[dbo].[Table1];

insert into [db_dest].[dbo].[Table1] select * from [db_src].[dbo].[Table1];
```

What other solid options do I have? Could [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) be faster?

Comment: Whether `MERGE` will be faster or not probably depends on how similar `[db_dest].[dbo].[Table1]` is before and after you have replaced all the rows. e.g. If it contains 1 million rows and your delete insert only ends up changing 2 of them then yes it will likely be a lot faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you need to remove all records from a table - consider using TRUNCATE TABLE instead. This is way faster, especially when the table contains many records, as each individual record deletion is logged, when using DELETE FROM.

Merge will generally not be faster than a pure TRUNCATE TABLE followed by INSERT, as Merge will have to compare the records, field by field, in the two tables, to be able to update a record that has changed from the source, or remove a record that is no longer available in the source.